# best solution for Django Composite primary-key from foreign-keys

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, many-to-many, composite-primary-key

I want to satisfy this relationship in a Django SQLite DB ([ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haYPz.png)), I have tried using both the [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) and [`models.UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) solutions that I've seen suggested.

myapp/models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)

class Article(models.Model):
    article_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class ArticleEditor(models.Model):
        class Meta:
        # RECOMMENDED
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['article_id', 'editor_id'], name="article_editor_id",)
        # DEPRECATED
        unique_together = (('article_id', 'editor_id'),)

    article_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Article,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    editor_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
```

In both cases, when I try saving an ArticleEdiotor object through the python console, I get this error:

```
>>> from myapp.models import User, Article, ArticleEditor
>>> a = Article.objects.get(article_id=2)
>>> u = User.objects.get(user_id=1)
>>> ae = ArticleEditor(a.article_id, u.user_id)
>>> ae.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: myapp_articleeditor
```

However, I checked the `sqlmigrate` command for the migration and it does `CREATE TABLE "myapp_articleeditor"`; but it still makes an `"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` that I don't want, as I'd like for my composite key (`article_editor_id`) to be the primary key. How to I achieve this?

And is this actually the best way to make a many-to-many relationship that has an intermediate table, like depicted in the diagram, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not support multi-column primary key, unique together is proposed workaround but you will still have one column to act as real id

There is no work being done on this topic for long time [Wiki article](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys), [django-compositepks](https://github.com/dcramer/django-compositepks)

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to the currently-accepted answer from 2020, it appears that as of September 2023, there *is* ongoing work to finally implement composite primary keys/foreign keys. If I understood the PR's discussion correctly, then they've already got composite primary keys working, but need to make it work with foreign keys as well before they can actually merge the changes.

See this PR for details: https://github.com/django/django/pull/17279